# cygwin c lang - system() - No such file or directory

Tags: c, cygwin

I am using cygwin64 to create c-lang apps on windows. There are two modules:

1. module.exe
2. recursive.exe

module.exe calls recursive.exe

```
strcpy(cmd,"C:/Users/t9sau2/Documents/PythonProjects/InsurityDeploymentAutomation/c/recursive.exe ");
strcat(cmd,"\"");
strcat(cmd,p);
strcat(cmd,"\"");
printf ("The command is %s\n ",cmd);
int ret = system(cmd);
```

When I execute module.exe using cygwin64 terminal, recursive.exe is successfully called and recursive.exe copies the files successfully. However when I execute module.exe in dos shell, it fails with below message -

> Value of errno: 2 The error message is : No such file or directory File copy failed.Copy manually

cygwin64/bin is in path variable. When I used getcwd() to get the current directory, it prints the correct directory. When I execute recursive.exe in dos shell, it executes successfully.

Comment: What happens when you type `C:/Users/t9sau2/Documents/PythonProjects/InsurityDeploymentAutomation/c/recursive.exe` in the cygwin command prompt? (NOT the Windows command prompt!)

Comment: recursive.exe in Cygwin throws "Command Not Found". ./recursive executes the program successfully.

Comment: Just a warning unrelated to your problem. Building command strings by concatenating pieces from different sources, and feeding the result to `system` is a recipe for disaster. What if `p` ends up being `hello"; rm -rf /*"`

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin's `system` uses Cygwin's command prompt, not Windows's command prompt. You have to give it a valid Cygwin command.

Comment: As per the C reference document for System, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system, System is available for both Windows and posix. However the argument should be a valid host command processor command. In Windows, I can call executable by just typing foo.exe. Hence I believe that would work from System command too. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: @TusharSaurabh Cygwin simulates Linux. Your "host" is Cygwin.

Comment: initially I had coded System("./recursive"). When it didnt work I tried with System("recursive.exe"), System("full_path/recursive.exe") and System("full_path/recursive"). In all cases I received the same error - No such file or directory.